# Installing Node.js 15.5.1 (latest version) results in error

Tags: node.js, installation, buffer, deprecated

I tried to install **Node js 15.5.1** (latest version) and this error occurred:

> (node:13440) [DEP0005] DeprecationWarning: Buffer() is deprecated due
> to security and usability issues. Please use the Buffer.allocUnsafe()
> instead

I downloaded the installer at *https://nodejs.org/en/*, I followed the installer's steps and marked the option to add the node references to the machine's path, however after a few minutes the installation stopped and sent me above error.

Related to js I have the **Code Runner** extension in Visual Studio Code, but otherwise nothing.
My operating system is Windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Node installer js managed to fix the error. I went to the installer again and clicked on the "Repair" option, shortly after at the command prompt I used node --version and everything is fine.